# Accepts nested attributes for multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two resources: Recommendations and Ratings.

Recommendations Model:

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings
end
```

Ratings Model:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :recommendation
end
```

Recommendations Controller:

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @product = Product.find(params["product_id"])
    @recommendations = Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products, :conditions => ["product_id = ?", (params["product_id"])])
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new
    @rating = Rating.new
  end

  def create
    #need to find_or_create new rating based on recommendation_id 
  end  

end
```

Recommendations Index:

```
<div id ="prods_container">
  <%= form_for @recommendation do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for @rating do |r| %>
      <% @recommendations.each do |rec| %>
        <%= rec.title %>
        <div id="rec_note_text"><%= r.text_field :notes %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a notes field for each of the "recommendation" objects which I need to update the ratings table in my `create` action/recommendations controller. How do I pass the correct ID's to my controller to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't related to your `create` action question, but does `rec.title` open a `<div>` without closing it? Or did you accidentally type an extra `</div>` when copying into StackOverflow?

Comment: Oops, copied over an extra div. Fixed. Thanks.